# ¿Como insertar muchos registros en Realm con Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift3, iphone, realm, insert

Estoy intentando realizar una inserción masiva de datos en Realm, pero lo está haciendo muy lento.

este es mi codigo:

```
            let realm = try! Realm()


            let group = GroupRealm()

            group.id = 1
            group.name = "test"

            try! realm.write { 
                realm.add(group)
            }

            var product = [String:AnyObject]()
            product["id"] = "" as AnyObject!
            product["code"] = ("") as AnyObject!
            product["detail"] = ("") as AnyObject!
            product["onHand"] = (0) as AnyObject!
            product["price"] = (0) as AnyObject!
            product["isSerialized"] = (0) as AnyObject!
            product["isLotNumber"] = (0) as AnyObject!

            var groupProduct = [String:AnyObject]()
            groupProduct["group"] = group as AnyObject!

            for r in 0..<300 {
                realm.beginWrite()
                for i in 0..<100 {
                    product["id"] = "\(i)-\(r)" as AnyObject!
                    realm.create(ProductRealm.self, value: product, update: true)

                    groupProduct["id"] = "\(i)-\(r)" as AnyObject!
                    groupProduct["product"] = product as AnyObject!
                    realm.create(GroupProductRealm.self, value: groupProduct, update: true)
                }
                try! realm.commitWrite()
            }
```

los objetos que estoy usando son estos:

```
class ProductRealm: Object {
    public dynamic var id: String = ""
    public dynamic var code: String = ""
    public dynamic var detail: String = ""
    public dynamic var onHand: Int = 0
    public dynamic var price: Double = 0
    public dynamic var isSerialized: Int = 0
    public dynamic var isLotNumber: Int = 0
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class GroupProductRealm: Object {
    public dynamic var id = ""
    public dynamic var group: GroupRealm!
    public dynamic var product: ProductRealm!
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
class GroupRealm: Object {
    public dynamic var id = 1
    public dynamic var name = ""
    public dynamic var update = Date()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Las pruebas en mi iphone 5s para insertar 30000 registros se demoran más de 30 segundos, mientras que en un proyecto viejo que tengo con sqlite se demora alrededor de 16 segundos.

He leído que realm es mucho más rápido en esto que sqlite por lo cual se que es un error mio, pero no doy con el D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno después de bastantes pruebas encontré una forma de reducir el tiempo a tan solo 1-2 segundos de creación de datos para insertar y 7-9 segundos de inserción (se puede bajar más si se muestran menos registros, por ejemplo si muestro cuando hace 1000 inserciones se reduce a 4-6 segundos).

Lo primero que tengo que decir, es que los objetos estaban mal, si bien en sqlite las relaciones de muchos a muchos se hacen con una tabla auxiliar, aquí sobra completamente, ya que uno puede insertar varias veces el mismo registro en un array, por lo que los objetos quedan así:

```
   class ProductRealm: Object {
        public dynamic var id: String = ""
        public dynamic var code: String = ""
        public dynamic var detail: String = ""
        public dynamic var onHand: Int = 0
        public dynamic var price: Double = 0
        public dynamic var isSerialized: Int = 0
        public dynamic var isLotNumber: Int = 0
        override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "id"
        }
    }

   class GroupRealm: Object {
        public dynamic var id = 1
        public dynamic var name = ""
        public dynamic var update = Date()
        let products = List<ProductRealm>()
        override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "id"
        }
    }
```

Esto significa que a diferencia de sqlite solo es necesario insertar los datos en una sola "tabla" y las referencias del mismo en la otra "tabla" lo cual lo hace mucho más simple y mejora un poco el rendimiento, sin embargo los tiempos de inserción seguían muy altos.

Después de muchas pruebas se me ocurrió usar el jsonObject para insertar, ya que la idea es traer estos registros desde un servidor, y para mi sorpresa esto redujo mucho el tiempo de inserción a comparación de los diccionarios, por lo que el código final quedaría así:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TestRealm
//
//  Created by Sergio Castro on 10/02/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 BasTechSoluctions. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Mostrar la ubicación del proyecto para ubicar la base de datos
        print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.absoluteString)


        DispatchQueue(label: "background").async { //Abrir un nuevo hilo para insertar de forma asíncrona
            autoreleasepool {

                let date1 = Date() // Inicia el conteo del tiempo

                let realm = try! Realm() // Instanciar realm en el hilo nuevo

                let products = realm.objects(ProductRealm.self) //Crear una lista de todos los productos

                //Crear grupo
                let group = GroupRealm()
                group.id = 1
                group.name = "test"

                try! realm.write { //Insertar/Reemplazar grupo, sin productos
                    realm.create(GroupRealm.self, value: group, update: true)
                }

                ///Crear json
                //Primero creo un String, donde ingreso todos los datos en formato [{},{},...]
                var stringJson = "["
                for i in 0..<30000 {
                    if(i > 0){ stringJson.append(",") }
                    let dataOrigin = "{\"id\": \"\(i)\", \"code\": \"\", \"detail\": \"\", \"onHand\": 0, \"price\": 0, \"isSerialized\": 0, \"isLotNumber\": 0}"
                    stringJson.append("\(dataOrigin)")
                }
                stringJson.append("]")

                //Convertir el String en Datos y luego pasarlo a jsonObject (esto para simular el proceso de descarga de datos)
                let data = stringJson.data(using: .utf8)!
                let jsonP = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [Any]

                //Mostrar el tiempo empleado para la creación del json en consola, el tiempo está en segundos por defecto
                let date2 = Date()
                var time = date2.timeIntervalSince(date1)
                print("Json creation in seconds \(time)")

                //Recorrer el json en grupos de 100, tantas veces haga falta para recorrer por completo el json, en este caso 300 veces
                let limit = 100
                for c in 0..<(jsonP.count / limit){
                    //Insertar/Reemplazar los grupos de datos
                    realm.beginWrite()
                    for i in 0..<limit{
                        let row = jsonP[i + (c*limit)]
                        realm.create(ProductRealm.self, value: row, update: true)
                    }
                    try! realm.commitWrite()
                    //Mostrar en consola la cantidad de procesos realizados vs la cantidad de registros actuales
                    print("\((c+1)*limit) / \(products.count)")
                }

                group.products.append(objectsIn: products) //Agregar los productos al grupo, aquí se pueden poner filtros

                //Actualizar el grupo, para que el array products tenga una referencia a sus productos correspondientes
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.create(GroupRealm.self, value: group, update: true)
                }

                // Calcular el tiempo de inserción y mostrarlo en consola
                let date3 = Date()
                time = date3.timeIntervalSince(date2)
                print("Insert time in seconds \(time)")

                // Calcular el tiempo total del calculo
                time = date3.timeIntervalSince(date1)
                print("total time in seconds \(time)")

            }
        }
    }
}


class ProductRealm: Object {
    public dynamic var id: String = ""
    public dynamic var code: String = ""
    public dynamic var detail: String = ""
    public dynamic var onHand: Int = 0
    public dynamic var price: Double = 0
    public dynamic var isSerialized: Int = 0
    public dynamic var isLotNumber: Int = 0
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class GroupRealm: Object {
    public dynamic var id = 1
    public dynamic var name = ""
    public dynamic var update = Date()
    let products = List<ProductRealm>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Bueno yo lo dejare asi, pero si encuentran una forma de optimizarlo se los agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que principalmente está haciendo que tardes más en insertarlo es abrir y cerrar varias `write transactions` dentro del `for`.

**Ésta sería una forma poco eficiente o incorrecta:**

```
let realm = try Realm()

for i in 0..<300 {

    try realm.write {

        // Inserts
    }

}
```

**En cambio, ésta otra sería la más eficiente y correcta:**

```
let realm = try Realm()

try realm.write {

    for i in 0..<300 {

        // Inserts

    }

}
```

**Para tu caso particular, yo haría lo siguiente:**

```
let realm = try! Realm()

let group = GroupRealm()

group.id = 1
group.name = "test"

realm.beginWrite() // -------------- Inicio de escritura

realm.add(group)

var product = [String:AnyObject]()
product["id"] = "" as AnyObject!
product["code"] = ("") as AnyObject!
product["detail"] = ("") as AnyObject!
product["onHand"] = (0) as AnyObject!
product["price"] = (0) as AnyObject!
product["isSerialized"] = (0) as AnyObject!
product["isLotNumber"] = (0) as AnyObject!

var groupProduct = [String:AnyObject]()
groupProduct["group"] = group as AnyObject!

for r in 0..<300 {

    for i in 0..<100 {
        product["id"] = "\(i)-\(r)" as AnyObject!
        realm.create(ProductRealm.self, value: product, update: true)

        groupProduct["id"] = "\(i)-\(r)" as AnyObject!
        groupProduct["product"] = product as AnyObject!
        realm.create(GroupProductRealm.self, value: groupProduct, update: true)
    }

}

try! realm.commitWrite() // -------------- Fin de escritura
```

Comment: :O gracias, solo que lo plantee así porque como mucho puedo hacer inserciones de 1500 datos a la vez, ya que el servidor no me mandara mas de esa cantidad por petición (para que el servidor no se resienta) y estaba intentando optimizar el código haciendo una emulación de la cantidad de peticiones que obtendré de la web.

de hecho el código que mencione que tengo en sqlite, hace las peticiones en grupos de 1500 y registrando 30000 productos se demora 16 segundos XD.

Comment: no pude probar el fin de semana tu codigo, pero acabo de probar y te mostraré los resultados:
44.9727689623833 segundos prueba con el código original,
35.1469470262527 segundos prueba con tu código,
7.60459595918655 segundos prueba con mi nuevo código (estableciendo en 30000 la variable limit). Al parecer el uso de diccionarios es muy poco eficaz.

Comment: Mi código era solo una propuesta. Al final has hecho lo mismo, que es poner el `for` dentro de la transacción, y no abrir una nueva por cada una.

Comment: amm no lo que hice fue cambiar los diccionarios por jsonObjects, osea si baja algunos segundos lo que dices, pero el uso de jsonObjects lo baja muchisimo.